# How to check if Panel has an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception, object-reference

in code-behind I declare a Panel:

```
Panel customPanel = new Panel(); // or simply Panel customPanel;
```

Then I can either assign it to an existing panel or not:

```
if (blablabla) customPanel = otherPanel;
```

Then I need to focus on the **customPanel** if it is assigned:

```
customPanel.focus(); // Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

How to check if **customPanel** is set to an instance?

```
if (customPanel != null) // the same
```

It only works when "blablabla" condition is true and customPanel is assigned to a panel.

Comment: Have you added the panel to a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use try catch block as following

```
try
{
    customPanel.focus();
}
catch(Exception nullObjectException)
{
    //do error handling 
}
```